# alert when scrollbar is at 75%

Tags: javascript

```js
document.onscroll = function() 
{
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.scrollHeight * 0.75) 
  {
    var height = document.documentElement.height;
    document.documentElement.height = height + 500;
    alert('75%');
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

I want this code to run every time the scrollbar reaches 75% of its height to add 500px then repeat the function when it reaches the 75% again.

The code works on my environment but if I scrolled fast I get multiple alerts and the 500px gets added more than once.

I tried the following:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight * 0.75
```

but it never alerted.

Comment: I'd use a global variable that will be changed upon `scroll > 0.75 * screen height`. This way you won't risk both the event firing at the exact equation point, and multiple times

Comment: And you may not get 75% exactly..... You are going to get some random decimal. onscroll also fires a lot so would not be surprised if you get weird results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such *height* property on **documentElement** object. To *update* the **height** you have to access **style** property *documentElement*.

Try this.

```js
document.onscroll = function() 
{
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.scrollHeight * 0.75) 
  {
    var height = document.documentElement.style.height;
    document.documentElement.style.height = (+height.slice(0,-2) + 500) + "px";
    alert('75%');
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 1600px">
  
</html>
```

Hope this helps :).

**EDIT:** Attached screenshots.

[image: reen]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Or maybe, tell me more what didn't work exactly. Because it works in my environment and I don't think I can reproduce the issue without more information.

Comment: i just noticed now that you put the javascript in the css box in the jsfiddle instead of the javascript box that why it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Use console for better results

```js
var sw_75 = false;
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (sw_75) return;
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.scrollHeight * 0.75) {
 console.log('75%');
 sw_75 = true;
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 var height = parseInt(body.style.height.replace("px", ""));
 body.style.height = (height + 500) + "px";
 sw_75 = false;
    }
};
```

```css
html, body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:1000px;"></body>
```

Comment: it is fired 2~3 times when i scroll fast to the bottom even with increased height more than 500